# Working on a https wordpress site on local enviroment but unable to connect

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, ssl, lamp

Working on a https wordpress site on local enviroment but unable to connect when trying to load pages.  I'm on ubuntu with apache essentially running lamp. I've set up local hosts before but this isn't working. I heard it has something to do with ssl certificates or something but should it be necessary since its local and if so how would I enable it

Answer (score 1):

SSl is A Little bit tough to setup if you want to develop wordpress on local environment just disable ssl and after making it live enable it back to ssl 
if some media or posts cant be encrypted and if ssl doesn't works just use wp-force ssl plugin from here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/ or if you cant setup ssl in live environment use plugin really simple ssl and all you need is a certificate thats it all will be taken care by plugin 
if you encounter any problem with that i can help you because i too even got the problem and this process helped me to get rid of this problem...